# How to cast `std::chrono::milliseconds` to `boost::posix_time::milliseconds`

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, boost-asio, c++-chrono

I am using a boost::asio::deadline_timer like so to set some timeout before an `async_read` operation on a *tcp socket*. I am using *boost 1.61*.

```
long time_out_millis = 2000;
boost::asio::deadline_timer theTimer(theSocket.get_io_service(), boost::posix_time::milliseconds(time_out_millis));
```

**Problem:**
Other parts of my code use `std::chrono::milliseconds`. I want use `std::chrono` instead of the `"long time_out_millis"` & if possible use `std::chrono::milliseconds` instead of `boost::posix_time::milliseconds`. How can I do that?

**Question:**
So, how can I use `std::chrono::milliseconds` here ? Is there a way I cast from `std::chrono::milliseconds` to `boost::posix_time::milliseconds` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Direct solution: `duration_cast<>`:

```
using namespace std::chrono;
using namespace std::chrono_literals; 

boost::posix_time::seconds(duration_cast<seconds>(2s).count());
```

Still not nice. But this is your key.

### BETTER NEWS

In any c++11 or higher scenario, simply

```
#include <boost/asio/high_resolution_timer.hpp>
```

And enjoy a timer completely parameterized on `std::chrono` from bottom to top. No more impedance mismatch:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b0f25db47cc7f230)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/asio/high_resolution_timer.hpp>
using namespace std::chrono_literals;

int main() {
    boost::asio::io_service svc;

    boost::asio::high_resolution_timer tim(svc);

    tim.expires_from_now(1s);
    tim.expires_from_now(100ms);
    tim.expires_from_now(3h);
    tim.expires_from_now(15'000us);
    tim.expires_from_now(15'000'000ns);
}
```

Note this would change your

```
long time_out_millis = 2000;
```

Into something like

```
Clock::duration timeout = 2000ms;
```

Comment: thanks for such a detailed answer. do you mean `Clock::duration` or  `std::chrono::system_clock::duration` ?

Comment: your answer is good. i get the point but not sure what you mean by `Clock::duration timeout = 2000ms;` . that doesn't compile. trying with `std::chrono::system_clock::duration timeout = 2000ms` gives some duration related compilation errors

Comment: `Clock` would be a typedef for `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock`

Comment: in the direct solution, shouldn't `seconds` instead be `milliseconds`? `boost::posix_time::milliseconds(duration_cast<milliseconds>(2s).count());`

Comment: @Quokka I think so. Cheers. Although these days I'd write `duration / 1s` or e.g. `duration / 1.0ms` etc I think,